Simulation of the OU process on fine and coarse scales
The Ornstein--Uhlenbeck process
$$
d X_t = \beta(\alpha - X_t) dt + \sigma dB_t
$$
has a known transition density. On the interval $[0, \Delta t]$ it is Gaussian with mean $\alpha + (X_0 - \alpha)e^{-\beta \Delta t}$ and variance $\sigma^2(1 - e^{-2\beta \Delta t}) / 2 \beta$. Assume that I would like to simulate this process on $[0, \Delta t/2]$ first, and then on $[\Delta t / 2, \Delta t]$, but then also be able to use the simulated random variables to simulate it on $[0, \Delta t]$, is this possible?
I know that if I solve the SDE using Euler-Maruyama, then I can just generate two increments on $[0, \Delta t/2]$ and $[\Delta t / 2, \Delta t]$, and then sum them up to obtain the increment over $[0, \Delta t]$.
The problem with using the exact transition density is that the variance over the increment of length $\Delta t / 2$ is $\sigma^2(1 - e^{-\beta \Delta t}) / 2 \beta$, but the variance over the full interval is $\sigma^2(1 - e^{-2\beta \Delta t}) / 2 \beta$, then sum of the variances over the smaller increments do not equal that of the bigger.

You figured out what the problem is: increments must be correlated. So, why doing something that only makes your life harder? I do not even understand why you consider numerical methods. This SDE has a well known closed form solution.

Thanks for your reply. I have a reason for doing this, I am aware that it seems strange. Is it possible to correlate them?

Yes,

In the link you sent $Y$ would be the RV over the coarse increment, $X_1$ and $X_2$ the increments over the fine intervals? I'm aware of the formula but not how to choose $\rho$.

The correlation can be derived once you know the closed form SDE solution. Start with that and show attempts.

Alright, simpler than I thought. Thanks!
